# Merge specific commit via the Github API

Tags: github-api

The documentation here:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/

says you can include in your body head a commit SHA1 but i cannot seem to get this to work.

Here is what i have tried sending

```
 HTTParty.post('http://github.com/api/v3/repos/sclayton/puppet-modules/merges', :basic_auth => auth, :headers=>{'Content-Type' => "application/json"},
:body => {
"base" => "stage",
'head'=>"sha: a593765fc0861e99b4c9538e75676c55be264f01"}.to_json)
```

and

```
'head'=>"a593765fc0861e99b4c9538e75676c55be264f01"}.to_json
```

and

```
'head'=>{"sha" =>"a593765fc0861e99b4c9538e75676c55be264f01"}}.to_json)
```

I was wondering if anyone had accomplished merging a single commit through the Github API?

Comment: What response do you receive from the API? Also, the documentation you linked to clearly states that both base and head are supposed to be strings. The second thing you tried *should* have worked. Without a response from the API though I can't help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the real GitHub API:

```
HTTParty.post(
  'https://api.github.com/repos/sclayton/puppet-modules/merges',
  :basic_auth => auth,
  :headers=>{'Content-Type' => "application/json"},
  :body => {
    "base" => "stage",
    'head'=> "a593765fc0861e99b4c9538e75676c55be264f01"
  }.to_json)
```

Note the significant difference in URLs. Unless you're using a GitHub Enterprise instance, your URL should **always** start with `https://api.github.com/`. Of course this is only a guess because you didn't provide the response you were getting from GitHub.

Comment: I apologize we're using an enterprise version of github so I masked the url. That being said, the response from github when using your example says: {"message"=>"Head does not exist"}

Comment: So the fact that you're using enterprise GitHub complicates things. There are *some* things that are not available in the Enterprise APIs that are in standard GitHub. I strongly doubt this is one of them. You're also certain that the particular commit (`'a593765...'`) actually exists on the `sclayton/puppet-modules` repo? Is it perhaps in a fork?

Comment: you were right. in the response when you query commits for a specific branch there are two sha responses and I was grabbing the wrong one.. the correct sha is the first one. Thanks. sorry for being so terrible.

Comment: @seanrclayton You weren't being terrible. You did nothing wrong. You made a mistake and no one is upset with you over it.